# definir tamanho de div de acordo com svg em js

Tags: javascript, div, resize

Boa tarde. Desculpe a duvida iniciante, mas gostaria de saber se é possivel utilizar o evento onresize do javascript para redimensionar uma div/container.

estou utilizando esse código:

```
var resizeTimer;
        window.onresize = function (event) {
            clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
            resizeTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                var s = d3.selectAll('g');
                s = s.remove();
                set_vars();
                drawGraphic();
            }, 100);
        }
```

mas ele só redimensiona o conteúdo se eu aumentar/diminuir a janela do browser.

Desde já, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Pelo compreendi deseja redimensionar uma div.

Então para tornar uma div ***resizeable*** deverá utilizar a propriedade `resize` do CSS.

Exemplo de uso:

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  resize: both;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div>Teste</div>
```

O evento `onresize` não irá redimensionar a sua div, apenas irá chamar uma função (criada por você) quando o utilizador redimensionar a div.

Portanto você pode utilizar esse evento apenas para adicionar outro comportamento á div assim que o utilizador começar a redimensionar a mesma.

[Documentação MDM Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize)

Answer (score 0):

O evento onresize é o evento de browser que é startado quando voce aumenta e diminue por isso ele so funciona nestes dois casos, você precisa identificar  quando voce quer redimensionar sua div , se for ao diminuir e aumentar mesmo seria desta forma
com JQuery

```
 window.onresize = $('#id-div').attr('style', `height:
 ${window.screen.height}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos. No meu caso, foi necessário utilizar um script externo, pois era necessário redimensionar a div pai e as div's filhas e seus respectivos conteúdos. Para isso utilizei o script "javascript-detect-element-resize".

link: https://github.com/sdecima/javascript-detect-element-resize